# Can't read an image from database

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to read an image from a SQL Server database, but I'm get an error:

> Parameter is not valid

Who can help me? How to fix it?

```
byte[] im = connection.ReadImg(id);

if (im != null)
{
   MemoryStream st1 = new MemoryStream(im);
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(st1);
}
else
   pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fn);

public byte[] ReadImg(string id)
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT photo FROM User WHERE id=" + id;
    byte[] image = null;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
       image = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch
    {
       image = null;
    }

    con.Close();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ReadImg() is returning valid data? That is likely the bit of code you need to share.

Comment: I think yes, I add ReadImg method here

Answer (score 2):

If `id` is a string, you have to pass it as a string:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT photo FROM User WHERE id=@id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

If not using the recommended parameter way, the problem is you need to have the string parameter enclosed in single quotes:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT photo FROM User WHERE id='" + id + "'";
```

This is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, id - is string. I tried your soluton, but doesn't works, the same error. I tried like this: 
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT photo FROM UserWHERE id=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

Comment: @JohnSmith Next, try putting brackets around the tables and fields: `[photo]`, `[User]`, and `[id]`, since they can conflict with keywords.

Comment: @JohnSmith I was refering to the problem.  You have to put those brackets around `[User]` because that's a keyword.  If it still doesn't work, then you have to confirm your table and field names in SQL Server — they aren't matching to the posted code.

Answer (score -1):

The `SELECT` statement does not return a scalar; you need to use `ExecuteReader` or similar;

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
using(reader)
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        // Do something with reader["photo"].
    }
}
```

To provide more we need the data types of `id` and `photo`.